# 2 jquery plugins don't work in one form

Tags: jquery

I have jquery validation and jqtransform in a form,but just one of them work:

```
    <!-- validation -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/sitestatic/scripts/validation/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/sitestatic/scripts/validation/languages/jquery.validationengine-fr.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/sitestatic/scripts/validation/jquery.validationengine.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <!-- end validation -->
    <!-- jqtransform -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/sitestatic/jqtransformplugin/jquery.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/sitestatic/jqtransformplugin/jquery.jqtransform.js" ></script>
    <!-- end jqtransform -->
    <script>
<!-- validation script-->
     var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function(){
                jQuery("#registrationForm").validationEngine();
                $("#id_StatusTypeCode").addClass("validate[required]")
                $("#id_PriceUnitCode").addClass("validate[required]")
                });
    $(function(){

    $("form").form();

    });
<!-- end validation script -->
<!-- jqtransform script-->
    $(function(){
                $('form').jqTransform({imgPath:'jqtransformplugin/img/'});
            });
<!-- end jqtransform script-->
    </script>
```

but just jqtransform work,what should I do?

Comment: Can you show a live example? Also, I suspect the `/sitestatic/jqtransformplugin/jquery.js`  to be the jQuery framework, which overwrites the previously defined jQuery framework + pkugins.

Comment: I think so,I thought both may work with jquery.js,but they didn't,I don't know what to do

Comment: for jqtransform--> http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/

Comment: for validation--> http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

Comment: I have already downloaded these files, and inspected the code. See my answer below for a fix.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `<script type="text/javascript" src="/sitestatic/jqtransformplugin/jquery.js" ></script>`. This imported Javascript file overwrites the previously defined jQuery framework + plugins.

**What happens?**

```
Load jQuery-1.6-min.js   Defines jQuery
Load validation files    Defined jQuery validation plugin
Load jquery.js           Overwrites the previously created jQuery object
                          ^ The jQuery validation plugin is deleted
Load jqtransform         Defined jqtranform plugin
```

The code below should work:

```
<!-- jQuery framework -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sitestatic/scripts/validation/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<!-- Validaiton -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sitestatic/scripts/validation/languages/jquery.validationengine-fr.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sitestatic/scripts/validation/jquery.validationengine.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<!-- end validation -->
<!-- jqtransform -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/sitestatic/jqtransformplugin/jquery.jqtransform.js" ></script>
<!-- end jqtransform -->
```

Comment: jqtransform is designed for jQuery 1.2.6. There may be compatibility issues with newer versions. Do you get any error messages?

Comment: I have this error in IE :Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0)
Timestamp: Fri, 11 Nov 2011 21:06:23 UTC


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 25
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://127.0.0.1:8080/airAgency/mastane/addtour/


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 21
Char: 13
Code: 0
URI: http://127.0.0.1:8080/airAgency/mastane/addtour/

Comment: hey buddy,I wanna use a beautiful validation plugin with another plugin to beautify form elements,do U know 2 plugins that work right together?that sounds like these to plugins don't wanna work together.

Comment: If you host your testcase online, I will have a look at it.

Comment: Post a comment when you have created an example of the code. I expect the asker to show some efforts, before I voluntary spend much time on the question.

Comment: what should I do exactly to clarify?

Comment: A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), with **working links** to external JavaScript files **and** the RELEVANT HTML code, ideally.